# Passing text from Fragment to Fragment to Activity onto receiving bitmap in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-studio, bitmap

I'm basically having 2 Fragments and 2 Activities.
Fragment1 has input texts which passes them to Fragment2. Fragment2 has Textviews where the previously typed text will be filled in. 
Activity1 makes a picture and sends it to Activity2. Activity2 receives that picture and gives you the opportunity to add the text created in Fragment2.

Now i want to save the picture to my SD card or gallery including the text. I know that i have to convert the Textviews to bitmaps and then "merge" them with the original picture, but how can i handle the communication between Fragment2 and Activity2?

This was my idea but i'm stuck at sending and receiving the texts:

```
public void setText(String top, String bottom){
    topText.setText(top);
    bottomText.setText(bottom);

    Bitmap topText = Bitmap.createBitmap(topText.getDrawingCache());
    Bitmap bottomText = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomText.getDrawingCache());
}
```

This happens in Fragment2.

```
imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTakenPhoto);
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
        getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(b);
    }
```

This happens in Activity2 (receiving of the picture)
If Fragment2 would be an Activity i would just send it with an intent like i did in Activity1 but this being a Fragment kind of confuses me.
Before i forget: Fragment1 and 2 are part of Activity2.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards

Comment: Are `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` attached to `Activity1` or `Activity2` or something else? You can retrieve it from the parent Activity via `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` or `FragmentManager.findFragmentById()` methods, depending on how you attach them to the Activity

Comment: @NitroNbg Yes, exactly, Fragment1 and Fragment2 are both attached to Activity2. That's exactly what i need, but how can i receive the bitmaps with the Fragment manager?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you should be able to use this inside `Activity2`:

```
Fragment2 frag = (Fragment2) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag2); //change the id with real id
String textInTextView1 = ((TextView)frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.textview1)).getText().toString();
```

And so on for all your `TextView` objects attached to `Fragment2` root view.

Comment: This is the way to do it!
It would be better to also check if the received fragment is null.
Depending on 'where' and 'when' you access the fragment, it would be a good idea to check if 'frag.getView()' returns null or not. But this is in most instances not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can save the data in the settings of the app like an database, and in the other fragment you get the data.
You can see more in [Saving Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

To write the data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = 
getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

To retrieve it:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```